# Differentiability of a Function on $C^1([0,1],R)$

Tags: functional-analysis

The function $F: V\to R$ is differentiable at $w \in V$ if there is a $F_w \in V^*$ (the dual space) s.t.
$$
\lim_{h \to 0 \in V}\frac{\|F(w+h)-F(w)-F_w(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0 \in R
$$

Let $[0,1] \subset R$ and $q \in C[0,1]$. Set $F:C^1[0,1] \to R$:
$$
F(w) = \int_0^1(\frac{1}{2}|\frac{dw}{dx}|^2+|w(x)|^2-q(x)w(x))dx
$$

I am trying to analyze the differentiability of $F$ and characterize $F_w$. The following theorem can be used directly:

Theorem:

If the $F$ above is differentiable at $w$, then the $F_w$ above is uniquely defined:
$$
F_w(h)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{F(w+th)-F(w)}{t}
$$

Comment: Why are you taking absolute values of the squares of real values?

Comment: The easiest approach I find is to look at $F(w+h)-F(w)$ and drop the higher order terms. So, for example, $(w'+h)^2-w'^2 \approx 2w'h$. So, $DF(w)(h) = \int_0^1 (w'+2w-q)h dx$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think that's a redundancy in the question. I think those absolute value signs are unnecessary. Nevertheless, they are in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda(w) = {1 \over 2} (w')^2+w^2-q \cdot w$ and note that
$\lambda(w+h)-\lambda(w) = w' \cdot h' +{1 \over 2} (h')^2 + 2w \cdot h + h^2- q \cdot h$.
In particular, if we let $\Lambda(w)h = w' \cdot h' + 2w \cdot h - q \cdot h$, we have
$\lambda(w+h)-\lambda(w) -\Lambda(w)h  = {1 \over 2} (h')^2 +h^2$.

Then
$\| \lambda(w+h)-\lambda(w) -\Lambda(w)h\|_\infty = \|{1 \over 2} (h')^2 +h^2\|_\infty$, and
the latter is bounded by $\|h\|^2_{C^1[0,1]}$ (there may be a constant depending on exactly how you define the $C^1[0,1]$ norm).

(As an aside, since the map $\Lambda(w)$ is continuous, this shows that $\lambda$ is differentiable and $D\lambda(w)h = \Lambda(w)h$.)

Then
$|F(w+h)-F(w) - \int_0^1 (\Lambda(w)h)(x) dx | \le \|h\|^2_{C^1[0,1]}$.

In particular,
$Df(w)h = \int_0^1 ( w'(x) \cdot h'(x) + 2w(x) \cdot h(x) - q(x) \cdot h(x))dx$.

(Continuity of $Df(w)$ follows from continuity of $\Lambda(w)$.)

Comment: How do you get this whole expression?

Comment: Look at my comment above.

Comment: The first term in your comment above should be $(w'+h')^2$, correct?

Comment: You are correct.